# Stuck on this task

Tags: python

From an online python course:
You will be given a website with 100 names. All names are in the form of a link. Each link leads to another 100 links.  You must use python to select the 18th link for 7 times, and print out the results.
my code so far:

```
z = 0
atags = []
listurl = []
#import modules
import urllib 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
newurl = "https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Desmond.html"
while z < 7:
    url = newurl
    z = z + 1
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    soup.find_all("url")
    a = soup.find_all('a')
    for x in a:
        atags.append(str(x)) 
    url_end_full = atags[19]
    url_end = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', url_end_full)
    url_end = str(url_end[0])
    newurl = 'https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/' + url_end  
    str(newurl)
    listurl.append(newurl)
    url = newurl        
print url
```

It does not work. It keeps giving me the same link...

this is the output:

```
https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Lauchlin.html
[Finished in 2.4s]
```

the answer was wrong when i entered it into the answer box.

Comment: Did you try 'print url' inside the 'while' loop?

Comment: Yeah. It prints the same link 7 times.

Comment: is it the last link? or the first?

Comment: Not the first one. Its the same link that it has been giving me.

Comment: what's the link? I cant seem to get the above script to work without the link

Comment: https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Desmond.html

Comment: I suggest you edit your question above to reflect where the link is and the exact output, as well as exactly what you are trying/where the error is to get an answer. The above code is giving me errors

Comment: Alright, i edited the post. It does not show any errors for me...

Comment: Please use a title that actually describes the problem, so that it will help readers searching for similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

1. `atags[19]` is not the 18th item, it is the 20th (`lst[0]` is the first item in a list).
2. `soup.find_all("url")` does nothing; get rid of it.
3. you do not need `re`.
4. The links returned are relative; you are doing a hard-join to the base path to make them absolute. *In this case* it works, but that is a matter of luck; do it right with `urljoin`.
5. While `str(link)` does get you the url, the "proper" method is by indexing into the attributes, ie `link['href']`.

With some judicious cleanup,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

# version compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    from urlparse import urljoin
    from urllib import urlopen
else:
    # Python 3.x
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from urllib.request import urlopen

START_URL = "https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Desmond.html"
STEPS = 7
ITEM = 18

def get_soup(url):
    with urlopen(url) as page:
        return BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'lxml')

def main():
    url = START_URL
    for step in range(STEPS):
        print("\nStep {}: looking at '{}'".format(step, url))
        # get the right item (Python arrays start indexing at 0)
        links = get_soup(url).find_all("a")
        rel_url = links[ITEM - 1]["href"]
        # convert from relative to absolute url
        url = urljoin(url, rel_url)
        print("  go to '{}'".format(url))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which, if I did it right, ends with `known_by_Gideon.html`